# Ping - guardar resultados positivos numa lista

Tags: python, thread, ping

Eu tenho este código, está funcionar bem, mas o problema é que gostaria de guardar os sucessos (ping com retorno) numa *list*, mas não sei fazer esse rastreio sucessos/fracassos.

```py
import subprocess
import threading

def pinger_menager():

   count = 1
   while count <= 255:
      address = "192.168.1."+str(count)
      for i in xrange(1, 2):
         worker = threading.Thread(target=massive_pinger, args=(address,))
         worker.start()

      count = count + 1

 def massive_pinger(address):
    try:
       res = subprocess.call(['ping', '-c', '1', address])
    except:
       pass 

 def main():
    pinger_menager()

main()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Uma forma de saber isto é verificar o retorno da função [`subprocess.call`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.call), é retornado *0* caso tenha sucesso, ou *1* caso falhe.

Para guardar os resultados numa lista você terá que criar um *array*:

```
lista = []
```

Na função `massive_pinger` verifique o valor da variável `res`:

```
def massive_pinger(address):
    try:
        res = subprocess.call(['ping', '-c', '1', address], stdout=subprocess.PIPE, 
        stderr=subprocess.PIPE)
        if res == 0: # Obteve sucesso
            lista.append(address)
    except:
        pass
```

Para imprimir os endereços da lista basta fazer:

```
def main():
   pinger_menager()
   for endereco in lista:
      print(endereco)
```

Como você está usando *threads*, é possível implementar um pouco o código com a classe [`Queue`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/queue.html).

Considere o código abaixo, baseado no seu, mas com uma abordagem um pouco diferente, usando uma [classe](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/classes.html):

```
from subprocess import check_output, CalledProcessError
from threading import Thread
from Queue import Queue

class PingNetwork:
    def __init__(self):
        self.lista = []
        self.queue = Queue()

    def pingManager(self, endereco):
        self.endereco = endereco
        alcance = 256
        for contagem in range(1, alcance):
            alvo = "{0}.{1}".format(self.endereco, contagem)
            self.queue.put(alvo) # Coloca o endereco atual na fila
            worker = Thread(target=self.enviarPing)
            worker.setDaemon(True)
            worker.start()
        self.queue.join() # O trabalho foi terminado

    def enviarPing(self):
        endereco = self.queue.get() # Retorna o endereco atual e remove o mesmo da fila
        try:
            check_output(['ping', '-c', '1', endereco])
            self.lista.append(endereco)
        except CalledProcessError: # Se a tentativa de ping falhar, a exceção é lançada
            pass # Operação nula, nada acontece
        self.queue.task_done() # A tarefa atual foi terminada

    def obterLista(self):
        return self.lista
```

O truque está em usar o método [`check_output`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.check_output), se a tentativa de *ping* falhar, uma exceção [`CalledProcessError`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.CalledProcessError) é lançada, caso contrário indica que a tentativa de *ping* teve sucesso.

Para usar na função principal:

```
def main():
    ping = PingNetwork()
    ping.pingManager('192.168.1')
    enderecos = ping.obterLista()

    for endereco in enderecos:
        print ("O endereco {0} respondeu com sucesso".format(endereco))

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Comment: O timeout já percebi. Mas com a mecânica assim qual é o propósito das threads (faça um `print endereço` em `enviarPing`)? Visto que está a fazer um ping de cada vez... O objectivo era 255 threads, cada uma a mandar um ping para um endereço diferente todas ao mesmo tempo

Comment: O que é a faixa de IP?

Comment: @Miguel Arrumei o código. Ficou mais parecido com o seu, deixei o *timeout* de *lado* para fazer isto o que você quer. Mais tarde edito e detalho melhor o código.